# not able to remove set of Linux directory using python

Tags: python

I am trying following to delete a set of directories in Linux which starts with the string of 'anonymous'-

```
import glob 
import shutil
a = glob.glob('anonymous*')
for b in a:
    shutil.rmtree(b)
```

a is fetching correct value(I printed and tested) b is a also getting correct values(I printed and tested but its not removing directories....

but if I pass a single value to b it removes that directory(I tested)

Not sure what is the exact reason....am I making any mistake?

Comment: Is there any error? Could you please `print(a)`?

Comment: You have the necessary permissions to delete the files, right?

Comment: Operating system? Python version? Any exceptions being thrown? Have you tried passing in a function with `onerror=func` to print out any error messages? Oh, and the obvious one ... are you in the right directory? Your code worked from the interpreter for me (ipython, python 2.7, OSX Yosemite)

Answer (score 0):

Use pythons pathlib to search the directories to delete inside of Python and delete them recursive with shutil:

```py
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/tmp/')
paths_to_delete = []

for child in path.iterdir():
    if child.name.startswith('anonymous') and child.is_dir():
        shutil.rmtree(child)
```